# Match only strings containing pairs/powers of 2 of a given character, using a regex

Tags: regex, formal-languages

I´d like your help creating a regex for this, I just can´t find the logic to acomplish it, I know almost nothing about regular expressions.

The regex is supposed to accept strings like these ones (containing a pair quantity of "a"):

```
aba (2)
aa  (2)
ababababaa (6)
aabbaba (4)
...
```

And negate:

```
bb (0)
aaa (3)
bab (1)
aabbabaa (5)
bbbbbbbaaaaaaabababb (9)
...
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could just form the regex that ensures you have exactly 2 `a` chars, and combine multiple regex for each combination (wherever it is allowed to have `non-a` char)

```
$ sed -n -r '/^(a[^a]?a|[^a]?aa|aa[^a]?|[^a]a[^a]a|a[^a]a[^a]|[^a]a[^a]a[^a])+$/ p'
aba
aba
aa
aa
ababababaa
ababababaa
aabbaba
aabbaba
bb
aaa
bab
aabbabaa
bbbbbbbaaaaaaabababb
$
```

So above regex ensures you have even number of `a` chars in string.

Note: whichever lines match your criteria are printed twice, and which don't are printed only once. Instead of `[^a]` you can use just `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The logic can be as simple as:

1. Match arbitrary length of non-`a` from the beginning
2. Match a pair of `a` with arbitrary non-`a` in between and after
3. Repeat (2) indefinitely with at least one occurrence

The regex:

`[^a]*(a[^a]*a[^a]*)+`

Annotated:

```
[^a]*           # Match arbitrary length non-a
(a[^a]*a[^a]*)  # Match a pair of a with anything in between and after
+               # Repeat the previous with at least one occurrence
```

Answer (score 0):

**Optimised**

```
var r= "aaaaabbabbbbaa".match(/(.)\1{0,}/g);

    var count=0;
    var startCharMustBe='a';
    for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {    
         if(r[i].length>0 && r[i][0]==startCharMustBe)
         {
           count=count+r[i].length;
         }
    }
    alert(count);
```

**Dynamic**

```
var r= "aaaaabbbbbbaa".match(/(.)\1{0,}/g);

var index=new Array();
var isExist=false;
var startChar;
for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {    
     startChar='';
     isExist=false;
     if(r[i].length>0)
     {
       startChar=r[i][0];
     }

    for(ii=0;ii<index.length;ii++)
    {
        if(startChar==index[ii].C)
        {
          index[ii].length=index[ii].length+r[i].length;    
          isExist=true;       
          break;
        }           
    }   

    if(!isExist)
    {

     var t= {"C":startChar,"length":r[i].length};
     index.push(t);
    }
}

for(ii=0;ii<index.length;ii++)
{
  alert(index[ii].C +" "+index[ii].length);
}

alert(r);
```